# PHP url rewriting using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
http://www.example.com/justridesbeta/jstride/vehicle
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/justridesbeta/addride
```

using htaccess.

Currently using

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]



  RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ justridesbeta/jstride/vehicle
  </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/justridesbeta/jstride/vehicle')
{
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/justridesbeta/addride");
    exit;
}
```

if you *really* need that