# Rewrite Url .htaccess

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a site with many html page in different directory ,and .htaccess file

```
 http://mysite.com/index.html 
.
.
.
http://mysite.com/design/index.html
.
.
.
http://mysite.com/doc/ui/index.html
.
.
.
```

I want to rewrite all of index.html page to :

```
http://mysite.com/doc.php 
.
.
.
http://mysite.com/design/doc.php
.
.
.
http://mysite.com/doc/ui/doc.php
.
.
.
```

I have a single page doc.php & I want to all of my index.html page rewrite to this page
and I can get query string url and get page value and $echo in doc.php

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you a simply wanted to use something other than `index.html` as as Directroy Index page, than you don't need to do a URL re-write at all.

Just put this config option in your Apache host config:

```
DirectoryIndex doc.php index.html index.htm
```

This will give preference to your `doc.php` when you are accessing the server using directory name only.  In other words requests with URL's like `http://mysite.com` or `http://mysite.com/design` will go to the `doc.php` file in those directories rather than index.html. If the directory doesn't have a `doc.php` file the server will then look for an `index.html` file.

Comment: I put the DirectoryIndex doc.php index.html index.htm in .htaccess file?

Comment: You can, though I would put it in the the hosts config file (httpd.conf or whatever based on your OS), as if you can avoid having to use .htaccess and can keep AllowOverride off, this is better performance-wise and Apache won't than have to look in every directory related to a request to see if an .htaccess file exists. Of course, if you are on some sort of shared host, you might have .htaccess as your only option.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `DirectoryIndex` command, you can easily change the index. You can append multiple files for the server to try if the previous one isn't available by separating different filenames with a space on the same line. Try not to use rewrites if they're not necessary.

```
DirectoryIndex doc.php
```

Put the previous in a `.htaccess` file in your root directory and it should make your directory index doc.php instead of index.php/html.

Answer (score 1):

Hi saeed same question in stackoverflow or you can take help form this url

[PHP url rewriting using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976809/php-url-rewriting-using-htaccess)