# Rewrite rule for url in php in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to use rewrite rule for may website.
I have a link

www.mysite.com/product.php?p_id=1212

Need to convert like

www.mysite.com/product/1212

Please suggest me the rewrite rule for .htaccess file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite Url .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044616/rewrite-url-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

please add this rule in your .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
 RewriteRule    ^product/([0-9]+)/?$    product.php?p_id=$1    [NC,L]
```